# Filter result of by.repeater

Tags: angularjs, protractor

Are any way to filter the result of by.repeater? I need that because I have one ngRepeat inside another ngRepeat and I want to see if the elements are in the correct group.
For example:

```
<div ng-repeat="group in itemsGrouped">
    <div ng-repeat="item in group.values">

    </div>
</div>
```

We need Something like this:

```
describe('group1', function(){
    group = ptor.findElements(protractor.By.repeater('group in itemsGrouped').filter('group.name == "group1"'));    
    it('should have one item', function(){
        expect(group.count()).toBe(1);
    });
});
// or
describe('group1', function(){
    groupCount = ptor.findElements(protractor.By.repeater('group in itemsGrouped')).count();    
    it('should have one item', function(){
        groupCount.then(function(count){
            for(var i = 0;i < count; i++) {
                ptor.findElements(protractor.By.repeater('item in group.values').filter('group.name == "group1"'));
                ...
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a built in filter

```
element.all(by.css('.items li')).filter(function(elem, index) {
  return elem.getText().then(function(text) {
    return text === 'Third';
  });
}).then(function(filteredElements) {
  filteredElements[0].click();
});
```

if you not already know it, take a look at [lodash.js](http://lodash.com/docs)

**edit**: the above example was copied from the [docs](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/api.md#api-elementarrayfinder-prototype-filter)

Comment: In that way, we can not share information between two ngRepeater and just find some information in the array of one ngRepeater.